# ¿Cómo cambiar el contenido de un select en base a otro select?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, select

Tengo dos selects cuyo contenido lo cargo con dos array y un foreach para cada select. El punto es que uno de esos selects esta incorrecto, ya que no me debería de mostrar todas las opciones, solo las que pertenecen a la opción del primer select. Como por ejemplo, seleccionas un pais y te deberían aparecer en el otro select solo las provincias de ese país.

En la página ya tengo cargadas las opciones del select que definirá las opciones del segundo, estaba pensando en hacerlo con un método que reciba como parámetro el id de la opción del primer select. Pero no se muy bien como implementar esto con Jquery y llamar a la función que esta en el modelo.

Esta es la función que traería las opciones concernientes al value del primer select, estaría en un evento on change del primer select. Pero no sé como realizarlo.

```
    public function obtenerSucursalesDeDistribuidora($idDeDistribuidora){
    $sql = "SELECT idDistribuidoraSucursal, nombre FROM trade.distribuidoraSucursal WHERE idDistribuidora =" . $idDeDistribuidora;
    return $this->db->query($sql)->result();
}
```

Este es la parte html con los selects.

```
<fieldset>
<legend class="form-legend">
    <label><i class="far fa-edit"></i> Registrar Distribuidora Sucursal: </label>
</legend>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control input-sm" name="idUsuarioHist" value="<?=$idUsuarioHist?>"/>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label for="new-usuario-numDistribuidoraSucursal">Distribuidora: </label>
        <!-- Primer select-->
        <select class="form-control input-sm" name="sl-distribuidora">
            <option value="">Distribuidora (Todo)</option>
            <? foreach ($distribuidora as $row) { ?>
                <option value="<?=$row->idDistribuidora?>"><?=$row->nombre?></option>
            <? } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label for="new-usuario-numDistribuidoraSucursal">Distribuidora Sucursal: </label>
        <!--Segundo select-->
        <!--Tambien traigo todas las opciones en un array, pero no debería ser así, solo deben estar
        las opciones concernientes a la opción del primer select-->
        <select class="form-control input-sm" name="sl-distribuidoraSucursal">
            <option value="">Distribuidora Sucursal (Todo)</option>
            <? foreach ($distribuidoraSucursal as $row) { ?>
                <option value="<?=$row->idDistribuidoraSucursal?>"><?=$row->nombre?></option>
            <? } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="new-usuario-registrar-distribuidoraSucursal" name="registrar_distribuidoraSucursal" value="Registrar">
    </div>
</div>
```

Este sería el evento en la página.

```
<script>
$(document).on('change','select[name="sl-distribuidora"]',function(){
    //Aqui iria el codigo que llame a la funcion del modelo, y cambie las opciones
    //del segundo select en base a la opción del primero.
});
```

Comment: Hola, te falta un `=`, debía ser `WHERE idDistribuidora=" . $idDeDistribuidora;` luego hace falta mas información, como el código html del problema.

Comment: Acabo de añadir el html.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona en sí? ¿Depuraste los datos, haciendo por ejemplo un `var_dump` de lo que obtienes en la consulta: `$this->db->query($sql)->result()` ? Por ejemplo, puede haber algún problema con la consulta, y si no hay datos no puede funcionar. Indica claramente cuál es el problema. ¿Y aquí, no hay un error de sintaxis: `<option value="<?=$row->idDistribuidoraSucursal?>"><?=$row->nombre?></option>`? ¡Ay! esa horrible mezcla de código. Analizar esa sola línea es un dolor de cabeza, preferíría concatenar todo en una variable, dentro de un bloque PHP.

Comment: En el HTML funciona normal todo, me carga las opciones para cada select que he traído en arrays para la vista. El problema es que en el segundo select no deben aparecer todas esas opciones, solo las concernientes a la opcion seleccionada en el primer select. Eso lo quiero hacer con una función en el modelo y un evento para que cada vez que se cambie el valor en el primer select, recargue nuevos valores en base al value del primer select, eso haciéndolo con la función que muestro.

El punto es que no sé como hacerlo. No sé que código iría en el evento.